# Where is the best place to check permissions?

Tags: wcf, architecture

My application have the following architecture:

Web service layer (wcf services)

Business logic layer

Data access layer

Where should I check permission? In Web services or in BL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer I would recommend checking access in the service layer, but it of course depends on your needs. In many scenarios I have built services where only some clients where allowed to access the service which - of course - is checked by WCF using certificates from the caller or similar.

The user of the client then also has a set of credentials allowing access to specific part of the data (which is checked in the BLL) or specific methods/endpoints of the service, which is checked by either WCF or the BLL depending of the nature of the user credentials and authorization logics.

But I agree that the DAL should not be involved.

Answer (score 1):

In general I would do at the web service layer as security is a high level concern. This is specially good for WCF as the security setting are configurable using config changes and not in code. So it is very easy to model security at WCFlayer.
DAL is definitely not the place to check security as it is too low level. A given web method may call many DAL methods and you may miss one, or a DAL method can be both allowed or disallowed depending on which web method it is called from.